# How to read text from a file line by line

Tags: c++, xcode, file, io

I am trying to read a text file *input.txt* which contains:

> John Smith
>
> 123 Any Street
>
> Dallas
>
> Texas
>
> 75275
>
> 2 0.79 13.20 6.50

but when I try and read the first line by using getline(), the whole file is copied into the string name instead of the first line. Here is my code:

```
string name;
ifstream fin("input.txt", ios::in);
getline(fin, name);
```

all I want name to contain is "John Smith". Any advice?

Comment: This is certainly `file` and `io`. It would help if you tagged your question with the environment and language you're using.

Comment: Possibly the file originates with Unix and has just LF for line endings, while your program is on Windows and searches for CRLF.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is right. It's enough for you to get the string "John Smith"
Try to learn a little bit more about **"carriage return"** or **"line endings"** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

The carriage return is different on different platforms.

example:

```
<CR> = 0x0D = '\r'
<LF> = 0x0A = '\n'
```

**Windows** uses bytes `<CR>+<LF>` to identify a newline... while **UNIX** systems use `<LF>`... **Mac** systems used to have only `<CR>` to identify a new line (sometimes called "classic Mac")... but now they switched to `<LF>` just as the UNIX standard.

So, your problem is probably that you have a different line ending standard. Try to use a better text editor (*Notepad++, Sublime, TextWrangler, etc*) to play with different line endings.